# Imposible centrar elemento en Bootstrap 5

Tags: html5, bootstrap-5

Luego de buscar en un montón de posts, quería saber porque no me funciona como a los otros este código.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="usr" class="form-label">Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="pwd" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

las sentencias `d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center` funcionan y lo muestran con fotos que el elemento está centrado tanto vertical como horizontalmente. Yo no consigo eso, solo consigo centrarlo horizontalmente y se queda pegado en la parte superior. [image: fail]
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Sí lo está centrando verticalmente pero no se ve porque el div que contiene el formulario se está ajustando a su contenido. Agrega un estilo para hacer que el div tenga un 100% del height del viewport.

```css
div.d-flex{
 height: calc(100vh);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
    <form autocomplete="off">
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="usr" class="form-label">Usuario</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <label for="pwd" class="form-label">Contraseña</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He visto que también funciona sin la función experimental `calc()`.

Comment: Sí, también. En todo caso es necesario que el div del form  tenga el 100% del alto del viewport para que align-items-center funcione.

Comment: porque funciona con `100vh` y no con `100%`?

Comment: Porque 100% es relativo al alto del padre, si el padre es de 100px entonces 100% serán 100px. 100vh es la altura del viewport, o sea el alto total de lo que se ve en pantalla.  https://devcode.la/tutoriales/unidades-vh-vw-css/